# How change the opacity of some text without change the opacity of background

Tags: css

I wrote this code

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E7E7E7;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background: red;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .3;
}

.overlay-top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
}

.container:hover .overlay-top {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="overlay overlay-top">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quisquam mollitia, explicabo, a animi earum vel et quidem consequatur facere asperiores alias dignissimos expedita dicta iusto tempora similique? Sit, vitae?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't change the opacity of text without changing the opacity of background even when I open a style for that text and set the opacity of the paragraph to 1 nothing changed 
Anybody can help me?

Comment: You cannot, however you have to tweak to get that flavor. Since when you make opacity to parent same is what reflect for child as well.

Comment: put the `opacity` on the **paragraph** not the overlay or use a color that supports transparency like rgba or hsla etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this condition just by opacity, you need to modify your background color to RGBA and then keep opacity of the whole overlay to 1. I just changed 2 properties from your code.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E7E7E7;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}


.overlay-top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
}

.container:hover .overlay-top {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="overlay overlay-top">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quisquam mollitia, explicabo, a animi earum vel et quidem consequatur facere asperiores alias dignissimos expedita dicta iusto tempora similique? Sit, vitae?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, if this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as the right answer and upvote.